# Is there a downside to sending a message to a nil object in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a long time C++ programmer, with a good amount of time in C#. I'm working in Objective C now however, and I'm wondering, is there a downside to sending a message to a nil object in Objective C?

For instance, I'm very used to doing this:

```
MyClass* c = NULL;
// ...
if( c != NULL ) c->MyMethod();
```

So in Objective C, I find myself doing:

```
MyClass* c = nil;
// ...
if( c != nil ) [c MyMethod];
```

So what I'm wondering is, is there any benefit at all to checking for nil? Is Objective C smart enough to not do any extra weird processing if I try to send a message to nil? Or is there some hidden cost that makes it worthwhile to continue checking for nil?

Comment: Just watch out for cases where you use the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C you do not need to check nil, messaging a nil valid is perfectly valid and most of the times will return nil or 0 if the return value is an integer. The return value is undefined if the return value of the message being passed is a float, double or struct though.

Comment: Messaging `nil` is also highly optimized (as is sending `-retain` or `-release` when GC is enabled), so it isn’t even a performance concern in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. That is the beauty of Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Messaging nil is no problem as long as the return value is meaning full in that context. Debugging can get complicated in some instance ...

"If the method returns any pointer type, any integer scalar of size less than or equal to sizeof(void*), a float, a double, a long double, or a long long, then a message sent to nil returns 0" (Apple - link below)
 -- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html (Sending Message to nil).